# Ошибка 500 при установке WordPress на IIS 7.0

Tags: wordpress, iis-7

Собственно, windows server 2008 r2 sp1. Установлена роль IIS с cgi. Установлен RewriteModule, php 7.4, mariadb 10.4. База создана, сайт создан, index.php в качестве начальной страницы прописан. phpinfo() работает.

Открываю первую страницу wordpress - ввожу данные созданной базы. Нажимаю "Далее". Получаю "500 - внутренняя ошибка сервера. Проблема с запрашиваемым ресурсом; ресурс не может быть отображен."
Права на корневую директорию c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\ для групп "Все", "Прошедшие проверку", "Администраторы", "Пользователи", "система", "IIS_IURSR" и "TrustedInstaller" выставлены "по полной".

На сколько я понимаю, установщик wordpress не может файл wp-config.php создать в корневой директории? Или я не прав? Куда ещё копнуть?

Comment: Ты в корне не прав, используя IIS.Я напр не знаю никого, кому бы удалось запустить чуть сложнее бложика на простейшее теме. И то, это было до того, как ВП обзавёлся гуттером со всеми выткающими.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1688
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-admin\setup-config.php(310): wpdb->db_connect()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1688

Это появляется после включения подробных сообщений об ошибках.

Comment: Исправляй вопрос, а не в комменты добавляй

Comment: Видимо, проблема с коннектом к базе данных?

Answer (score 0):

c:\Program Files\PHP\php74\php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "c:\Program Files\PHP\php74\ext"
extension=mysqli
```